# SwiftySound doesn't work in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I implemented sound effects on my app (shooting game) using [SwiftySound](https://github.com/adamcichy/SwiftySound/blob/master/Sources/Sound.swift) .
But if set a sound when touched a target, sometimes the sound isn't played.
I don't know why sometimes it is played but sometimes isn't.

**Code:**

```
class ViewController: ViewController {

    var soundManager: SoundManager = SoundManager()

    //.....

    func touchedTarget(){
        soundManager.playSE()
    }
}

class SoundManger {

    let tapSE: Sound = Sound(url:Bundle.main.url(forResource: "tap", withExtension: "mp3")!)!

    init(){

    }

    func playSE {
       tapSE.play(numberOfLoops: 0, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**Edit**

1.added "DispatchQueue.main.async{} in "playSE" but didn't work.

```
func playSE {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        tapSE.play(numberOfLoops: 0, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

2.added "DispatchQueue.main.async{} in "touchedTarget()" but didn't work.

```
func touchedTarget(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        soundManager.playSE()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be that you might be calling this on the background thread when it should be on the main thread.

In your view controller or wherever you are calling the sound try using:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    SoundManager().playSE()     
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work...the sound is played per touching 5 targets.

Comment: You should also show us the code of how you are trying to play the sound. No one would be able to dissect the problem otherwise

Comment: It's fine, the more detail you give the more others will be able to help, I should've specified though that I meant how you are trying to play the sound from the view controller and not from the sound manager.

Comment: I'm sorry again. I added the code that I tried and how call "playSE" from ViewController.